# Regex for multiple of 1000 accepting values greater than 25000 and decimal not allowed

Tags: regex

I have two combinations:

1. For checking multiple of 1000 which is `^[1-9]+[0-9]*000$`.
2. For checking value greater than 25000 which is `^\\d{6,}$|^[3-9]\\d{4}$|^2[5-9]\\d{3}$`.

When I tried to combine two regex with positive lookahead operator like below,

`^(?=[1-9]+[0-9]*000)(?=\\d{6,}$|^[3-9]\\d{4}$|^2[5-9]\\d{3})*$`

Its  taking values such as 25000100,35000100,which is not a multiple of 1000.

Is it possible to achieve both scenarios through one regex?

Comment: Try [`^([1-9]+[0-9]*000|\d{6,}|[3-9]\d{4}|2[5-9]\d{3})$`](https://regex101.com/r/gK1qY4/1).

Comment: Per the tag wiki: "Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool."

Comment: I wonder. Why are you using regex to solve a math problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```
^([1-9]\d{2,}|[3-9]\d|2[5-9])000$
```

https://regex101.com/r/vJ8xU6/3

Answer (score 2):

```
^(2[5-9]\d*|[3-9]\d+|[12]\d{2,})000$
```

[See it in action](https://regex101.com/r/aB0eY5/2)

The idea is:

- `2[5-9]\d*` - 25-29 with optional digits after that is >= 25
- `[3-9]\d+` - 3-9 with one or more digits after that is > 25
- `[12]\d{2,}` - 1 or 2 with two or more digits after that is > 25
- `000` - add three zeroes at the end for 1000 divisibility

Comment: Won't match numbers greater than 199,000

Comment: @BrendanAbel, it will. Did you even try it? `{2,}` means two or more, not exactly two.

Comment: I should have been more precise. It won't match numbers greater than 199,00 that start with 2[0-4], like 234,000

Answer (score 2):

Obviously any string ending in 000 is a multiple of 1000, so given a string X000, let's just worry about the X.

- If X is >=3 digits (matches `[1-9]\d\d\d*`), then X000 >= 100000 > 25000
- If X is 2 digits and the first digit of X is > 2 (matches `[3-9]\d`), then X000 >= 30000 > 25000
- If X is 2 digits and the first digit of X is 2 and the second digit of X is >= 5 (matches `2[5-9]`) then X000 >= 25000 = 25000.

Any other possible X is going to result in a smaller number (or something that isn't a number), so just throw those together into a group `([1-9]\d\d\d*|[3-9]\d|2[5-9])` for the prefix.

`([1-9]\d\d\d*|[3-9]\d|2[5-9])000`

*See Also*: https://regex101.com/r/bV1kN3/1

Answer (score 0):

Use any number range regex generator.
On open ended ranges, just use a 1 plus 0's equal to the the number of digits
of the lower range plus two more.

For your case it would be 25 to 1000 giving a regex of
`(?:2[5-9]|[3-9]\d|[1-9]\d{2}|1000)`.

This gives unique alternation segments.

```
 (?:
      2 [5-9] 
   |  [3-9] \d 
   |  [1-9] \d{2} 
   |  1000
 )
```

Strip off the 1000, then add the open ending on the largest number of \d's.
Works every time. Then just tack on the number of tens you want 000, etc.

```
 (?:
      2 [5-9] 
   |  [3-9] \d 
   |  [1-9] \d{2,} 
 )
 000
```